# Scrolling in a storyboard with several views

Tags: xcode, audio, storyboard, scrollview, transition

I´m creating an app that is simply a Storyboard with images, and an audio for each image. Im also planing to make some animations on every view on top of the image. Like a book where you swipe between the views, and on each view theres an audio and some animations. Ive realised that im maybe have been working in the wrong direction. Im using several views with modal transitions. It seems there might be a better way to go about it to get the scrolling transition style, which I cant seem to get with the current transition. Can I get the scrolling transition between different views, or does anyone have any idea of how to go about it?

Ive been searching around but haven´t found a thread that suits my question.

Comment: Do u want to make slideshow?

Comment: And yes you have get right answer of previous question than why you have not accept it?

Comment: Sorry, I accepted it now. Yes, like a slideshow you could say. It´s a children's book with several images, and on every image I want a voice reading the text.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you want to make slideshow like a book.

I have never done it my self but found some good example on internet.

I hope it will help you to get started.

1. [Apple's iBooks Dynamic Page Curl](http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2010/02/apples-ibooks-dynamic-page-curl.html)
2. [PaperStack Alpha](http://api.mutado.com/mobile/paperstack/)
   [PaperStack Alpha Source Code](https://github.com/lomanf/PaperStack)

All The Best.....

Comment: Its definitely a way to go about creating a book-like app. However I would like the transition to resemble the scroll-view transition.

Comment: Is it possible to add several UIViewControllers with their own view as subviews to a UIScrollView?